# ScrollView or TableView as the cell for a horizontal Table view

Tags: ios, gridview, scrollview, tableview, cell

I am aiming for a kind of horizontal table view where each cell (let's now saw column) is also a scrolling area.

Apple discourages you to use a scroll view inside a table view cell however since my table view will be rotated I think it could work out.

Has anyone tried this before and if so would you recommend how I am proposing to do this or would you suggest using some kind of custom view / grid framework out there ?

Quick doodle of the idea:

[image]